# django-pagination to paginate django-filter results

Tags: django, django-filter, django-pagination

I'm trying to paginate results of django-filter.

- Django 1.8.3
- django-filter 0.11.0
- django-pagination 1.0.7

I have configured view/templates as it is suggested in related documentation, my views

```
class ItemFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        template_name = 'library/items.html'
        model = Item
        fields = ['type','publishing','author','tags']
        order_by = ['id']

def itemimages(request):
    f = ItemFilter(request.GET, queryset=Item.objects.all())
    return render_to_response('library/images.html', {'filter': f})
```

my template

```
{% extends 'library/base.html' %}
{% load pagination_tags %}

{% block title %}Library Index{% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <ul class="rig columns-3">
        {% autopaginate filter 2 as filter_list %}
        {% for obj in filter_list %}
            <li>
                <a href="/library/{{ obj.id }}/">
                    <img src="{% static "/" %}{{ obj.cover.url }}"/>

                    <p>{{ obj.title }}<br/>{{ obj.national_title }}</p>
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        {% paginate %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}

{% block sidebar_block %}
    <form action="" method="get">
        {{ filter.form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

but all I can see is error message (it works without autopaginate block)

```
KeyError at /library/

'request'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/library/
Django Version:     1.8.3
Exception Type:     KeyError
Exception Value:    

'request'

Exception Location:     /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py in __getitem__, line 71
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python2.7
Python Version:     2.7.5
```

Please help me to identify where I am wrong. Documentation on django-filter suggests that list can be obtained as `f.qs`, but it never worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rendering your view with the `render` shortcut instead of `render_to_response`, so that the `request` object is available in the template context.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def itemimages(request):
    f = ItemFilter(request.GET, queryset=Item.objects.all())
    return render(request, 'library/images.html', {'filter': f})
```